# ¿Cómo puedo modificar la arquitectura de mis urls?

Tags: url

Estoy teniendo problemas con las entradas para WP personalice las urls de mis entradas que deberían quedar cómo: dominio/categoría/subcategoría/entrada, pero WP no las modifica.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: WordPress no me permite agregar la subcategoría en las entradas personalizadas, ni editarlas en la publicación

Comment: Y eso es un problema de programacion? o un problema de wp???

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!